# What is the purpose of a [field] + 0 in a T-SQL select Statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I ran across something in a T-SQL view that I had never seen before, and was curious what the purpose of it would be. The view was performing a left hash join on some tables, and the ID column of the first table was selected using `a.ID + 0`. I've never seen this in the wild before, and could not find anything similar on StackOverflow.

```
SELECT a.ID + 0 ID, a.FIELD1, a.FIELD2 
  FROM myDatabase.dbo.SomeTable as a LEFT HASH JOIN ...
```

I had to remove the `+ 0` statement from the view because ID field in the view appeared to be nullable, even though the original table data source listed the column as non-nullable.

What would be the purpose of the `ID + 0` in the select statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It converts a string to an INT when possible, and throws an error otherwise.

Consider:

```
select sql_variant_property('1', 'BaseType')     -- varchar
select sql_variant_property('1'+0, 'BaseType')   -- int
select sql_variant_property('ABC'+0, 'BaseType') -- Error
```